# Java use Apache common compress to unzip file

Tags: java, compression, apache-commons, unzip, apache-commons-compress

I have a zip file with a directory like below:
[image]

Is there anyway I can Apache common compress to decompress the entire zip file, so whenever a directory is a tar file or a tgz file, it will also be decompressed to the directory.

Or I have to decompress each directory one by one? Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You can recursively unzip/untar but you'll have to write the logic yourself, most likely.

Comment: I would say one by one. As the functionality goes unzip does not recursively decompresses inner archives. Same as zipping which would not compress inner directories to form an archive before it compresses the main directory. Also while decompressing files first you will have to check if the file format is eligible/appropriate for decompressing.